# The Nested Triangles Theorem (in the complex plane). It is possible?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Today I've read a known theorem in **Complex Analysis**, the so called **The Nested Rectangles Theorem**. In the first part of this theorem and proof that I've read, is enunciated the classical theorem, and in second part ensure that eventually (all but a finite numbers) all the rectangles lie inside an arbirary small disc.

I've thought about the possibility of a theorem for triangles, notice that I don't require equilateral triangles. (I say that in previous sequence of rectangles we can find a triangle lie in the first, and including the third, and so on with the second triangle and the next three rectangles, I don't know if this intuituion is good or useful. Too I've thought about the possibility of use barycentric coordinates.)

> **Question.** Can you state and give a proof of **The Nested Triangles Theorem**?

I believe that it could be a nice and useful exercise. **Thanks in advance.**

Comment: It isn't neccesary a second part of your theorem, only a similar theorem.

Comment: Is the nested rectangles theorem the following statement? "If $r_1\supset r_2\supset r_3...$ is a sequence of closed axis-parallel rectangles in the plane such that their diagonal tends to zero, then there is precisely one point contained in all of them"?

Comment: Yes @Wojowu, I hope that you can see it in http://www.open.edu/openlearn/science-maths-technology/mathematics-and-statistics/mathematics/complex-numbers/content-section-4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a closed triangle in a plane to be a convex hull of three non-collinear points. Note that a closed triangle is a closed set in $\Bbb R^2$. For a closed triangle, define its diameter to be the longest of its sides (which is also a maximal distance between points in this triangle). The the following holds:

> If $t_1\supseteq t_2\supseteq t_3\supseteq...$ is a sequence of closed triangles diameters of which tend to zero, then there is precisely one point contained in all of them.

I will prove there is at least one point. Showing that there is at most one follows easily on diameter condition.

Suppose there is no point contained in all of the triangles. Then $t_2^c,t_3^c,...$ (complements of the triangles) form an open cover of $t_1$ (can you see why this is true?). Because by [Heine-Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem) $t_1$ is compact, this open cover has a finite subcover, let's say it's $t_{n_1}^c,t_{n_2}^c,...,t_{n_k}^c$, where $n_1<n_2<...<n_k$. But $t_{n_1}^c\cup t_{n_2}^c\cup...\cup t_{n_k}^c=t_{n_k}^c$, which means $t_1\subseteq t_{n_k}^c$. But then $t_{n_k}\subseteq t_{n_k}^c$, which is a contradiction, as $t_{n_k}^c$ is non-empty.

Let me just note that this can be generalized to any nested family of closed sets with diameters tending to zero. The existence of a point is an instance of the following more general phenomenon:

> A set $X$ in some topological space is compact iff it has *finite intersection property*, i.e. if the following holds for every family $\mathcal F$ of closed subsets of $X$: If every finite subfamily of $\mathcal F$ has nonempty intersection, then so does whole $\mathcal F$.

After seeing my argument above, it will be instructive exercise to try to prove this equivalence.

Comment: Very thanks much, I remember all basics in general topology that you use, but now I don't know why obtain cover all $t_1$ with the complements that you cited. If you can explain it, add a comment, but I say that your proof is very nice, I will try learn and refresh my mathematics in this site in future seasons. Very thanj @Wojowu

Comment: Thanks too I've studied the *finite intersection property*, that is useful in functional analysis.

Comment: We are assuming that intersection of all triangles is empty. This means precisely that for every point $p$ in the plane there is a triangle $t_i$ which _doesn't_ contain $p$, or to say in a different way, the complement of $t_i$ _does_ contain $p$. So every point $p$ is contained in at least one of the complements. Is that clearer now?

Comment: Yes thanks, now I understand, very thanks much @Wojowu

Answer (score 0):

You can also prove the following statement: in a [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space) metric space any decreasing sequence$(T_n)$  ($T_n \supset T_{n+1}$ for all $n$) of closed subset with diameters $\textrm{diam}(T_n)\to 0$ has an intersection consisting of a unique point. The uniqueness is easy, since the intersection, if non-void, must have diameter $0$. To show that it is non-void, take a point $x_n \in T_n$ for every $n$. We have 
$d(x_n,x_m) \le \textrm{diam}(T_n)$ for all $n \le m$, so the sequence $(x_n)$ is [Cauchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence). Let $x = \lim x_n$. Since for all $n_0$ $x$ is the limit of the sequence $(x_n)_{n\ge n_0}$, and the closed set $T_{n_0}$ contains this sequence, we have $x\in T_{n_0}$. This is true for any $n_0$, so $x \in \cap_n T_n$.

Comment: Very thanks much @orangeskid , your proof of this generalization is very clear and useful.

Comment: @Juan López González: You are welcome!  This is a good drill.  Just as an observation, compare with this case $T_n=(0, \frac{1}{n})$.

Comment: Very thanks much **orangeskid**